# Bootstrap Modal Fade Out Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've added some basic animation to the closing of the modal box, so that it zooms out to an element:

```
$(function(){

    var $modal = $('.modal');
    $modal.on('hide', function () {

        if (!$modal.isAnimating) {

         // $('.modal-backdrop.in').fadeTo(250, 0);        // fade out backdrop

            var $target = $('#zoomout-target');
            var pos = $target.offset();
            pos.top  -= $(window).scrollTop();
            pos.left -= $(window).scrollLeft();

            $modal.css({top: pos.top, left: pos.left, transform: 'scale(0.1, 0.1)', opacity: 0});

            $modal.isAnimating = true;
            setTimeout(function(){
                $modal.modal('hide');
                $modal.isAnimating = false;
            }, 750);

            return false;
        }

        $modal.css({top: '', left: '', transform: '', opacity: ''});
    });
});
```

The problem is that the backdrop "hides" the target element to which the modal box zooms out.

So I added the commented line above `$('.modal-backdrop.in').fadeTo(250, 0);` which fades out the backdrop very nicely, but it looks like I'm missing something because then the page freezes.

It seems like the backdrop is still on, capturing all of the mouse events, etc, even though transparent.  So the backdrop is not visible, but is making the page unusable.

How can I get rid of the backdrop at the end of the `fadeTo` animation?

### EDIT:

I noticed that the problem is with the .modal-backdrop and .modal-scrollable overlays, so this snippet instead of the offensive one resolves the issue, but there's has to be a cleaner solution IMO:

```
$('.modal-backdrop.in').fadeOut(600, function(){
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
    $('.modal-scrollable').hide();
});     // fade out backdrop
```

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2 and [Bootstrap Modal](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/releases) 2.2.5

TIA

Comment: can you show a bastebin example of the problem or insert the url of the page ?